# What spells does the Sorcerer Elemental Bloodline Arcana apply to?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer, bloodline

> Bloodline Arcana: Whenever you cast a spell that deals energy damage,
>   you can change the type of damage to match the type of your bloodline.
>   This also changes the spell's type to match the type of your
>   bloodline.

I'm having a hard time figuring out when I apply my chosen element (which is fire) to spells using this ability.

Is it any spell that applies one of the elements, acid, cold, fire, electricity? Does the spell have to have the word "energy" in it, or elemental in it? Or does it apply to any spell that does damage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It applies to any spell that does energy damage, which is **any spell that does Acid, Cold, Electricity, Fire, or Sonic damage**. Energy damage is a misnomer, as it refers specifically to *elemental* damage. It does not include Force, Negative Energy, Positive Energy, or any other damage type. Only damage types that can be reduced by [Resist Energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resist-energy) are considered to be energy damage.

[James Jacobs backs this up](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=476?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#23772), as does this [glossary entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Damage).

For example, you could apply your bloodline ability to a Cone of Cold to make it deal Fire damage instead of Cold damage, but you could not apply it to Magic Missile or Inflict ____ Wounds.

Comment: Oh, excellent - so it doesn't have to have to SAY energy or elemental, it just needs to be one of those five types?

Comment: @REactionFaye just like the ability says, as long as it deals energy damage you can change it (and if it has an spell type such as Acid, that changes to your type)